# Android Emulator is not starting

Tags: java, android, emulation

I was load the android developers emulator. I created a virtual device. When i click the start button, it showing the boot screen. But it don't start. Here are screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: how many minutes did you wait ?

Comment: It normally takes a long time on windows. How long have you waited?

Comment: It can easily take 15-20 minutes to start up on a slow computer.

Comment: @Krish: Very valid point. On my ancient old dev machine it took a v4.0.3 emulator about 20 minutes to start up the first time I ever tried it. Thank goodness we can snapshot with the latest versions of AVD Manager.

Comment: Did you search here, and read the other 30 or so questions about problems starting AVDs?

Comment: İt started. But too slow. I can't use. My system is: 2 gb ram, 128 mb graphics :P 2 ghz processor.

Comment: That's the emulator for you. iOS FTW!

Answer (score 0):

just wait, it takes very long until it has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the adb then delete the emulator and create a new one. Start the new one and it should work.